# Initialization section in C

Tags: c, delphi

I'm translating simple encryption unit from pascal to C. In pascal I have initialization and finalization sections. In initialization section some procedure that generates key is done. This key generation procedure is needed to be done only once, when code is loaded. Do C has equivalent of initialization and finalization?

Comment: Also tagged C++ the accpeted answer would also work in C with minor adjustements regarding data types: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8412630/694576

Comment: @alk this is not equivalent of `initialization` section, just an awkward workaround.

Answer (score 4):

If using gcc a function can be attributed `constructor` and will then be called prior to `main()`. Analogous there is the attribute `destructor`, which makes a function to be called after `main()`.

More on this here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

To state this explicilty: **Those attributes are gcc specific**. Their functionality is **not part of the C Standard** and likely to **not** be **supported by other C compilers**.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in C exactly like Delphi's `initialization` and `finalization` sections.

You have two main options:

1. If the key can be evaluated at compile time, then you can use static initialization.
2. Otherwise you'll need to put the initialization into a function and call that function at runtime. You could call the initialization function early in your program's execution, or perhaps use lazy initialization.

Looking at the possibilities in option 2, the choice is often down to how the library is used. If you expect your code to be called simultaneously from multiple threads then lazy initialization can lead to trouble. In that scenario, an explicit initialize function passes the buck to the caller. Usually, I personally would generally prefer an explicit initialize function because it is easy to understand and reason about.

This is an area where C++ is rather more capable. Static initialization in C++ can be used to invoke your code via the constructor of the object being initialized.

If you showed the Delphi code then we'd be better placed to advise which option would be best.