# Timed once flag

Tags: c++

I see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337463/4806882) answer we can use `std::once_flag` in order to call a piece of code once:

```
std::once_flag onceFlag;

{
    ....
    std::call_once ( onceFlag, [ ]{ /* my code body here runs only once */ } );
    ....
}
```

Is there in the standard something like `timed_once_flag` that resets after a time, so the piece of code can be called again?

```
timed_once_flag timedOnceFlag(5s);

{
    ....
    std::call_once ( timed_once_flag, [ ]{ /* called again after timeout */ } );
    ....
}
```

I searched about this but it's possible that I am not using the adequate search terms.

EDIT:

Why I need this: in my case, I have multiple threads that can display a MessageBox to the user, so if an error occurs, it is ussually identical in all threads (e.g.: connection error) and I want the application to display the MessageBox only once with the possibility to display it again in the future only once.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I added the explanation

Comment: It seems like bad UI. Instead of MessageBox (which requires a user action) could you try something like tray notification? So it appears, shows necessary info but does NOT break the user activities.

Comment: The answer is no, there is nothing in the standard yet that gives you what you need.

Comment: No, a `once_flag` can't be used for something that is supposed to occur more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The **onceFlag**, which is an object of `std::once_flag` **class** is key here.

The internal state of `std::once_flag` object is set, so that there is no second execution of `std::call_once` function.

Here if you notice, the standards exposed only **one constructor with out arguments** for `std::once_flag` class ,And no overloaded assignment operator. Standards might have declared a private assignment operator or used "Explicitly delete special member functions. (C++11)".

**As far as I know, there is no way you can change/modify  the set internal sate.**

Try this odd way, if you seriously require....

Declare different `std::once_flag` flags

```
std::once_flag flag1,flag2,flag3; //Three different flags.

    {
        ....
        std::call_once ( flag1, [ ]{ /* my code body here runs only once */ } ); //track first thread call
        std::call_once ( flag2, [ ]{ /* my code body here runs only once */ } ); //track second thread call
        std::call_once ( flag3, [ ]{ /* my code body here runs only once */ } ); //third third thread call

    }
```