# code that runs once in a lifetime

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make a program that associates a selected file with a hard drive serial number so it doesn't run on any other hard drive. The part where I have to set the hard drive serial number should run only once in the lifetime of the program.

I have no idea how to implement this and the solutions on the internet use macros, which I am not familiar with. I am hoping to implement this using visual studio 2017 and Windows 10.

Comment: Your task can be split into several independent sub tasks. Which do you have problems with? What did you come up with so far?

Comment: What happens if someone clones your hard drive ? Does the executable run only "once" ?

Comment: I hope you are not trying to protect something valuable with this mechanism. It takes a few hours to an hacker to disassemble your program, find the function "IsThisTheRightSerialNumber?", and modify to always return true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412630/how-to-execute-a-piece-of-code-only-once

Comment: "run only once in the lifetime of the program" - ambiguous, which lifetime: current execution life, or published / release version lifetime  ...  if 'selected file' already exists at 'program' start up, what should program do?  a) confirm and when matches proceed with normal operation? b) confirm and when does not match exit with error notification? c) other

Comment: what i have come up with: -get the serial number of the hard drive.-modify a file with my program to not run except if it is installed on the hard drive chosen(still have that to figure out).it looks pathetic, because it IS. as I said i just crossed the beginner level, I'm not even sure if I have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file on disk and write hash of serial number string appended with some other data into a file, and read on the next run of your program. You can use openssl for this.

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
...
  string tohash = serial + "secret_suffix";
  unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // == 20
  SHA1(to_hash.c_str(), to_hash.length(), hash);
  write_to_file(hash);
```

You can run this while installing your application.

Comment: THANK U SOOO MUCH, don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 4):

[std::call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) will only run once for the duration of a program.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
void set_serial_number()
{
    static std::once_flag flag1;
    std::call_once(flag1, [](){ std::cout << "Set hard drive serial number\n"; });
}
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MVZJH91445)

You can call `set_serial_number` as much as you'd like, but the logic contained within the lambda passed to the call of `std::call_once` will only execute once.

e.g.,

```
int main(){
    set_serial_number();
    set_serial_number();
    set_serial_number();
}
```

Output:

> Set hard drive serial number

Comment: will it execute once in a program's lifetime

Comment: @BishoyYouhanna: Yes. The `once_flag` that is contained within `set_serial_number` is `static` meaning there's only one of them for the duration of the program, and it also stores some state (e.g. a boolean tracking whether it has been used in a call before or not).

Answer (score 2):

Static function / class members are guaranteed to only ever exist once.  So something like

```
class myThing {
    public:
        static const std::string hardDiskId;   
    private:
        std::string queryHardDiskId();
};

const std::string myThing::hardDiskId = queryHardDiskId();
```

will ensure that your hard disk id is only queried once.